# Terraform s3 bucket notification having multiple topics

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform

I am trying to write a flexible/dynamic resource for aws_s3_bucket_notification which may have variable topics for the specified s3 bucket. For one bucket, I may have just 2 prefixes and 2 topics and for others 4 or 5 and so on... I was thinking of using a map function which will store the "prefix" and "SNS ARN" for each prefix type as the events will be the same. I need to create a s3_bucket_notification which will have all the topics in it without having to manually write each of the topics. Any suggestions?

Example

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification" {
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id}"

  topic {
    topic_arn     = "$map.value" ###prototype
    events        = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
    filter_suffix = "$map.key" ###prototype
  }
}
```

Comment: By using something like primitive loops

Answer (score 2):

If my understanding is correct, the codes should like this:

```
variable "sns_top" {
  type = "map"

  default = {
    dev  = "topic1"
    uat  = "topic2"
    prod = "topic3"
  }
}

variable "bucket_name" {
  default = "my-tf-test-bucket-dfsfddsf"
}

data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}

resource "aws_sns_topic" "sns_topic" {
  count = "${length(keys(var.sns_top))}"
  name  = "sns-topic-${element(values(var.sns_top),count.index)}"
}

resource "aws_sns_topic_policy" "custom" {
  count = "${length(keys(var.sns_top))}"
  arn   = "${element(aws_sns_topic.sns_topic.*.arn, count.index)}"

  policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement":[{
    "Sid": "default",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {"AWS":"*"},
    "Action": [
      "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
      "SNS:SetTopicAttributes",
      "SNS:AddPermission",
      "SNS:RemovePermission",
      "SNS:DeleteTopic"
    ],
    "Resource": "${element(aws_sns_topic.sns_topic.*.arn, count.index)}"
  }]
}
POLICY

  depends_on = ["aws_sns_topic.sns_topic"]
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  bucket = "${var.bucket_name}"
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "default" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"

    actions = [
      "s3:PutObject",
    ]

    resources = [
      "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket.arn}/*",
    ]

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:root"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "default" {
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id}"
  policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.default.json}"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification" {
  count  = "${length(keys(var.sns_top))}"
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id}"

  topic {
    topic_arn     = "${element(aws_sns_topic.sns_topic.*.arn, count.index)}"
    events        = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
    filter_suffix = "${element(keys(var.sns_top),count.index)}"
  }
}
```

The codes hit an error explained in below link, but you should be fine to use it for further codings, such as how to use `count.index` with maps.

```
* aws_s3_bucket_notification.bucket_notification.0: Error putting S3 notification configuration: InvalidArgument: Unable to validate the following destination configurations
```

Refer:

[How do I avoid the error "Unable to validate the following destination configurations" when using S3 event notifications in CloudFormation?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/unable-validate-destination-s3/)

Comment: Thanks much @BMW. I will take a look at your suggestions. I wasn't sure if we can use the below   count  = "${length(keys(var.sns_top))}"
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id}"

  topic {
    topic_arn     = "${element(aws_sns_topic.sns_topic.*.arn, count.index)}"
    events        = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
    filter_suffix = "${element(keys(var.sns_top),count.index)}"
  }

Comment: You can. Only in this special case, because of the error `Unable to validate the following destination configurations`, you need statically name your S3 bucket.  I did have a try, still can't make it work. But the code with `count.index` and map usage are right.

Comment: All I needed to do was to have multiple notifications of the same s3 bucket without having to manually key in all the notifications in the resource definition but passed them using a map. I was going though this one as well. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/6934. It looks like there is a limitation.

Comment: I can't get the error working..Any clue in getting this resolved?

Comment: I tried and gave up. If you have business or developer account of AWS (not free), maybe raise a ticket and ask help from AWS support directly. This error needs instruction from them directly.

Comment: I don't think this will work, since it tries to declare multiple separate `aws_s3_bucket_notification` blocks. It's a limitation of AWS that you can only have one subscription per bucket, and a known bug in terraform that (instead of erroring out) it will simply create one of the various subscriptions at random each time you `terraform apply` https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/271